# Наследование и разработка своих компонентов

Tags: c++, gui, qt5, qml, qtquick

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять, как переопределять поведение стандартных QtQuick Controls, в частности Calendar. В доках сказано, что для изменения внешнего вида календаря есть специальный стиль CalendarStyle. Этот стиль позволяет менять отдельные части календаря, навбар, делегат дней недели, бэкграунд и т.д. Проблема в том, что не понятно, как поменять отдельный атрибут конкретной части.  Т.е. как сделать, допустим, отображение дней недели какой-нибудь Tahoma и размером 14 пунктов. Стиль предлагает свойство:

```
dayOfWeekDelegate: Component
```

Если определить его, то вы полностью перепишите делегат, и все, что у вас останется от дефолтного отображения дней недели, это то, что календарь создаст 7 делегатов. =) Весь их внешний вид придется реализовывать заново. Мне не верится, что это сделано настолько криво. В связи с этим вопрос: как правильно переопределять внешний вид и логику стандартных QML компонентов?